# Error in odata.request method with "PUT" option

Tags: jquery, odata, datajs

I want to perform update operation on my odata service data.

I have read many things about browser support for put and delete with ajax call.But in my code I can perform method:"DELETE" perfectly.even get and post are done nicely.
Now when I am doing "put" or "merge", its giving error "HTTP request failed".

Here is my code:

```
 OData.request( 
                { 
                    requestUri: query, 
                    method:"PUT",
                    data: { UserName: "user3", EmailId: "User2@XYZf",Comments:"qwerty uiopfg" } 
                }, 
                function (insertedItem) { 

                    $("#doc").append('<div>Done</div>');

                }
                , function(err){


                        $("#doc").append('<div>'+err.message+'</div>');

                        });
```

Edit: can any one give a simple OData.request demo code with method:"PUT" option, which is running properly.

Comment: Please use Fiddler or similar HTTP tracing tool to see the error response. If the service is setup to report debug information it should contain more information as to why it failed.

Comment: error message is "HTTP request failed" and status code is 400.

Comment: Can you please follow this blog to enable debugging messages on the service: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx